# Remove :html reponse to Devise Passwords Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to prevent users from accessing the html Devise page users/passwords/new, as I have made all my devise pages respond to :js.
It's all working for my Registrations and Sessions, but I can't seem to make it work with the Passwords.

I have set the routes to overwrite the controller:
`devise_for :users, controller: { passwords: 'users/passwords' }`

I have reset the navigational formats in that controller:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
      clear_respond_to
      respond_to :js

****** rest of devise code

end
```

And I have set up `devise.rb`

`config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :js]` (even if I remove html here it still does not work)

I've even deleted `new.html.erb` from the `views/devise/passwords` folder.
But I still have access to the url `users/passwords/new`

Of course if I use a link with `remote: true` it does render my `new.js.erb` just like it should.

Also the fact that it only reponds to :js prevents Devise from working if I enter a mail in the field I get a `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

Anyone has ever done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I've found a solution (?)

I just add this block in my `confirmations_controller`

```
def new
  super
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

So that users can still access the modal if the form is `remote: true`, but can't access the html version, because it raises an `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Could this cause any further problems?